# Cordova Plugin - Javascript Interface

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, apache-cordova

I'm following this tutorial:

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/createplugintutorial/

But the `Step 3: Design the JS interface` has no information at all there.

Also the `Step 5: Test the plugin` is missing.

Could somebody, please, specify here on this thread what would be the `JavaScript` interface for this plugin?

I think this would be very helpful for lot of people.

Here is the `Android` code:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("getNextAppointment")) {
        int minutes = args.getInt(0);
        this.getNextAppointment(minutes, callbackContext);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void getNextAppointment(int minutes, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    if (minutes > 0) {
        callbackContext.success("Plugin is working");
    } else {
        callbackContext.error("minutes must be > 0");
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question specifically, but the plugins that the Apache Cordova guys maintain are mirrored on GitHub. I used them as a guideline when creating my plugin's javascript API. See https://github.com/apache?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cordova-plugin-&type=&language=

Comment: Thanks!, that's a good advice.